# grep those matching lines which contain single quotes

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want to matches those line of words:

```
{'ID': 'X.id: 4243.4, Y.id 534534', 'text': 'text - text'}
{'ID': 'X.id: 4247.4, Y.id 534534', 'text': 'text - text'}
{'ID': 'X.id: 42233.4, Y.id 534534', 'text': 'text - text'}
```

and I use this `regular expression` to match them:

```
{'ID': 'X.id: [0-9]+.[0-9], Y.id [0-9]+', 'text': 'text - text'}
```

I tested it on https://regexr.com/ and it works.

However I tried to used this with grep using this command:

```
cat raport.log | grep "{'ID': 'X.id: [0-9]+.[0-9], Y.id [0-9]+', 'text': 'text - text'}"
```

Where do I do the mistake?

Comment: Use it with `-E` option. Also, escape the dots to match literal `.` chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works. You can add the answer. thank you for your help

Comment: @userunknown OP does not use backticks in the code, that was formatting in the post that was corrupted  [at Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49168890/2).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  may either use the ERE POSIX pattern by adding the `-E` option or change the `+` quantified subpatterns to their equivalents with `*` (e.g. `[0-9]+` => `[0-9][0-9]*`) (or escape `+` in GNU `grep`).

```
s="{'ID': 'X.id: 4243.4, Y.id 534534', 'text': 'text - text'}"
echo "$s" | grep -E "{'ID': 'X\.id: [0-9]+\.[0-9], Y\.id [0-9]+', 'text': 'text - text'}"
echo "$s" | grep "{'ID': 'X\.id: [0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9], Y\.id [0-9][0-9]*', 'text': 'text - text'}"
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/VKvCp1)

Note that you need to escape the dots to match literal `.` chars.